# mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for error

Tags: php, apache2, mod-fcgid

**update**: Just looked at the cache update times of long queries and they did not collide with server crash time.

**update2**: Found the cause of the problem. Ad server is down and the server hangs even though it seems we set socket timeouts properly. Is there any way to test timeout behaviour?

We have a very busy server. ~3K concurrent connections
The server has 32GB ram 2xCPUs. We have service unavailable error issues. 
The server does not respond with 500 error and the error log shows hundreds/thousands of lines:

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/fcgi-bin.d/php5-default/php-fcgi-wrapper
```

We think it can be a configuration error or a database connection/query error.
A php process updates a cache which is a very very complex query result. 3 separate queries run each twice a day. I have enabled the slow query log. I suspect if the query exceeds the php run time limit 20 secs in our case (set in the following files). Any help is appreciated.

We use apache worker mpm model with mod_fcgid.

Here is fcgid.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
SocketPath /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock

# Communication timeout: Default value is 20 seconds
IPCCommTimeout 20

# Connection timeout: Default value is 3 seconds

IPCConnectTimeout 3
```

And /etc/apache2/conf.d/php-fcgid.conf file:

```
<IfModule !mod_php4.c>
```

# Path to php.ini <96> defaults to /etc/phpX/cgi
    DefaultInitEnv PHPRC=/etc/php5/cgi

```
# Number of PHP childs that will be launched. Leave undefined to let PHP decide.
# DefaultInitEnv PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 8

# Maximum requests before a process is stopped and a new one is launched
DefaultInitEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 5000
# Maximum requests a process handles before it is terminated
MaxRequestsPerProcess 1500
# Maximum number of PHP processes.
MaxProcessCount       45

# Define a new handler "php-fcgi" for ".php" files, plus the action that must follow
AddHandler php-fcgi .php
Action php-fcgi /fcgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper

# Define the MIME-Type for ".php" files
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# Define alias "/fcgi-bin/". The action above is using this value, which means that
# you could run another "php5-cgi" command by just changing this alias
Alias /fcgi-bin/ /var/www/fcgi-bin.d/php5-default/

# Turn on the fcgid-script handler for all files within the alias "/fcgi-bin/"
<Location /fcgi-bin/>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Apache2 worker mpm config:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers         10
MaxClients           2048
ServerLimit          2048
MinSpareThreads      30
MaxSpareThreads      100
ThreadsPerChild      64
ThreadLimit          100
MaxRequestsPerChild   5000
```

We looked at the instructions on this web page and loaded high server config:
http://2bits.com/articles/apache-fcgid-acceptable-performance-and-better-resource-utilization.html

**update**: Just looked at the cache update times of long queries and they did not collide with server crash time.

**update2**: Found the cause of the problem. Ad server is down and the server hangs even though it seems we set socket timeouts properly. Is there any way to test timeout behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is pretty well covered by [google](http://www.google.pl/search?q=mod_fcgid%3a+can%27t+apply+process+slot+for). It looks like you have to play a bit with configuration (with options like MaxProcessCount).

I'd advice replacing apache with nginx. I experienced better performance. Also, nginx uses a lot less memory than apache. I'm using php-fpm for fast cgi.

Comment: I googled before asking this question. MaxProcessCount is set to 45. And the last time the server failed, it was not loaded. We plan to move to nginx however it is not a memory issue. The server shows it has 10GB memory free.

Comment: It's not only about memory. Nginx is also more efficient than apache.

Comment: Ironically this question is no. 1 on google when I enter the error message :-P

Comment: @cebe at the time I gave an answer it wasn't :P

Comment: Moving to Apache isn't always an option, our supplier only supports Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Move -> to nginx as soons as possible.
Try -> Caching with APC for single server memcached for distributed systems or file cache systems
Use -> DB indexes properly. It is one of the most important things I have ever experienced.

Comment: apache2 php-fpm do not take advantage of apc. we use file cache since it is a single server.

Comment: Actually it does - http://voidweb.com/2010/07/the-perfect-lamp-stack-apache2-fastcgi-php-fpm-apc/

Comment: mod_fastcgi does but mod_fcgid does not. Should we switch to mod_fastcgi?

Comment: well I didn't pay attention that you are using fcgi. However my experience shows me that fastcgi performs better than fcgi and it is much more stable under high load. So you should switch it and I guess that will help pretty much.

Comment: Found the problem. it's socket timeout issue. I've updated the question. Hope find a solution.

Comment: I think "move to another software" is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

restart you server.I have soveled this problem use this way~